# EXCEL VBA: Check if the value in Column B in the current workbook exists in another Workbook on 2 sheets before extracting data from certain columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have been slowly learning vba code recently and I am looking to create a macro that performs these specific tasks. I have been digging around other threads to try to see if I can scrap together something that can run but other threads didn't have the exact answer I was looking for.

1. Working on a Workbook labeled " 5/31 Reports" with sheet 1 labeled "New".
2. Part of the code prompts you to open a previous report "5/30 Reports" that contains 2 worksheets "New" and "Previously reported" to compare and extract data from.
3. Code will scan through each row of Column B of the "5/31 reports" Workbook. It will take that value and compare it to both sheets "New" and "Previously reported" on an older workbook.
4. If the value exists at all in the older workbook, it will extract the data from that same workbook on column "J" and "K" of where the value was found and will input that data on Columns "J" and "K" of the Newer "5/31 Reports" workbook.

The main issue I had is extracting data from the other workbook. I know it's a mess, but I am still learning all of the concepts.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Edited code because having 2 different worksheets with the same name is confusing.

```
Sub checkSalesorder()



    Dim FileName As Variant
 

    '//Change the file extension for the file filter, accordingly
    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
        FilterIndex:=1, _
        Title:="Select a Workbook")
        
        
Dim wbBook1 As Workbook
Dim wbBook2 As Workbook

Set wbBook1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wbBook2 = FileName

Dim wsSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet3 As Worksheet
Dim check As Long
Dim notes As String
Dim Newpromise As String
Set wsSheet1 = wbBook1.Worksheets("NEW ")
Set wsSheet2 = wbBook2.Worksheets("NEW  PREVIOUS")
Set wsSheet3 = wbBook2.Worksheets("PREVIOUSLY REPORTED")



Dim count As Integer
Dim LR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LR = wsSheet1.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

wsSheet1.Range("B" & LR).Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Row = 2



Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With Application.WorksheetFunction
check = wsSheet1.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B").Value
   count = wsSheet2.CountIf(wksdata.Range("B:B"), check) + wsSheet3.CountIf(wksdata.Range("B:B"), check)

End With

If (count > 0) Then

notes = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "I").Value
Newdate = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "J").Value

Cells(wsSheet1.Cell.Row, "I").Value = notes
Cells(wsSheet1.Cell.Row, "J").Value = Newdate

End If


ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Select

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've stored your current data (workbook 1) to an array, then stored the values in column B inside a dictionary to do the checks faster.

Then created a function to loop through the workbook's sheets and update the new data to the array with your current data:

```
Option Explicit
Sub checkSalesorder()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wbBook1 As Workbook: Set wbBook1 = ThisWorkbook
    'hold the current data of sheet "NEW " inside an array
    Dim current_data As Variant: current_data = wbBook1.Worksheets("NEW ").UsedRange.Value
    
    'Create a dictionary holding all the values from wbBook1 column B
    'To use a Dictionary variable you need to go to Tools-References-Check: Microsfot Scripting Runtime library
    Dim current_values As Dictionary: Set current_values = load_current_values(current_data)
    
    'Now lets find the values in that dictionary to worksheets 1 and 2
    'because the other file only contains the 2 files, we can make a separate procedure to check both with one code
    Dim wbBook2 As Workbook: Set wbBook2 = get_file
    check_for_new_data current_values, wbBook2, current_data
    
    'Paste the current_data to its worksheet with the new data updated
    wbBook1.Worksheets("NEW ").UsedRange.Value = current_data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
Private Function load_current_values(arr As Variant) As Dictionary
    
    'Init the dictionary
    Set load_current_values = New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'assuming your data starts at row 2, change if needed
        If arr(i, 2) = vbNullString Then GoTo next_row 'ignore blank data in column 2 (B)
        If Not load_current_values.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
            load_current_values.Add arr(i, 2), i 'add new data to the dictionary holding its row number
        End If
next_row:
    Next i
    
End Function
Private Function get_file() As Workbook

    Dim FileName As Variant
    '//Change the file extension for the file filter, accordingly
    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
        FilterIndex:=1, _
        Title:="Select a Workbook")
    'check if the user actually selected a workbook
    If Not IsEmpty(FileName) Then
        Set get_file = FileName
    'in case no workbook was selected
    Else
        MsgBox "No workbook was selected, please run the program again and select a workbook."
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End
    End If

End Function
Private Sub check_for_new_data(current_values As Dictionary, wb As Workbook, current_data As Variant)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'loop through all the worksheets in the workbook (assuming there are only the 2 you need)
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        retrieve_new_data ws.UsedRange.Value, current_values, current_data
    Next ws
    
End Sub
Private Sub retrieve_new_data(new_data As Variant, current_values As Dictionary, current_data As Variant)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim current_row As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'again, assuming your data starts at row 2 (1 is headers) and column A
        If current_values.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
            current_row = current_values(arr(i, 2)) 'get row number from current_data for this value
            current_data(current_row, 10) = new_data(i, 10) 'equal current_data column 10 (J) to new_data column (J)
            current_data(current_row, 11) = new_data(i, 11)
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate you for answering.
I am having trouble running the code. I do see that it's saying
"User defined type not defined."

As you can tell, I am still fairly new to this. Where would I look to debug this?

Thanks again.

Comment: @Jason it's hard to test without the data... when you get the error if you press "debug" there will be some word highlighted. That means either the variable was not declared or the data inside the variable didn't match the variable type.